# YouTube Data API V2.0 after April 20, 2015

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api, deprecated

My Android App is using YouTube Data API V2.0 for parsing YouTube Playlist.

But I heard that some APIs will be discontinued at April 20, 2015.

Is YouTube Data API V2.0 included in Discontinued APIs?

Can I use YouTube Data API V2.0 after April 20, 2015?

Comment: I would check with the source that told you they were being discontinued.

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube-api-list),

> most API functionality that was subject to that policy will continue to be available until April 20, 2015

So, the answer is no, you won't be able to use it.